# Android GPS. Location Listener does not want to acquire a fix :(

Tags: android, gps

Here is a code below that suppose to listen for GPS updates and send notifications to main activity

However it does not seem to be working :)

No errors, only onLocationChanged is not called!

Funny thing is: when I run some other app to get GPS fix and after that start my app => onLocationChanged gets called, only accuracy is degrading, and eventually fix is lost.

I also tried to add to this code GPS listener=> it works, satellites in view got reported every second, only fix is never accuired.

What the hell is going on? :)

public class PhoneGPSpos{

```
private Handler myHandler = null;
private LocationManager lm;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private Location currentBest;
Context m_context;
```

public PhoneGPSpos(Context context, Handler handler) {

```
    myHandler = handler;
    m_context = context;


    lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

 //  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 //  boolean xtraInjection=lm.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,"force_xtra_injection",bundle);
 //  boolean timeInjection=lm.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,"force_time_injection",bundle);

   currentBest = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() 
   { 

           public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
           { 
                Log.w("Compass", "Loc");

            if (location != null)
            {
                currentBest = location;

                Message msg = new Message();

                msg.arg1 = 5;
                myHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            }
           } 

           public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle 
           extras) {
            Log.d("Compass", "Stat");
           } 

           public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("Compass", "Prov e");
           } 

           public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("Compass", "Prov d");
        } 
   }; 
}

public void requestGPS()
{
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    Log.d("Compass", "gps requested");
}

public void stopGPS()
{
    Log.d("Compass", "gps stopped");
    lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

public synchronized  Location getBest()
{
    return  currentBest;
}
```

}

Comment: where are you testing? Indoors?

Comment: not. As I said: "other apps are able to get fix". when I switched back to my app just after that onLocationChanged is getting called only accuracy is degrading. And fix eventually is lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figure out that this is an issue that was also seen by other people: apparently (at least on some phones) GPS listener works much worse if Camera is active.

[Problem with getting GPS data when using CameraPreview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950026/problem-with-getting-gps-data-when-using-camerapreview)

[Android: Losing GPS signal strength on some phones when I start up the Camera and SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045659/android-losing-gps-signal-strength-on-some-phones-when-i-start-up-the-camera-and)

[Camera Preview and GPS reading in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353876/camera-preview-and-gps-reading-in-android)

Created Andorid issue for that http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20098

If someone has a solution pls share

Comment: be sure to accept your own answer so others can find your solution quickly.

Comment: I've seen this happen when I request a network location at the same time. Trying to find a SO question related to that right now, in case someone has a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

```
Check for permissions in your projects AndroidManifest.xml file

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: GPS_PROVIDER does not need internet permission.

Comment: FINE location is in. COARSE not. Im not using network. I only need GPS

Answer (score 0):

Where are you testing? Indoors?
What providers are the other apps using? Network Provider?

My guess is that the apps that are working use Network provider and since you are getting the last known, it will return that location from the previous app location ping. The Network provider helps allocate gps satellites by giving a general location. So when you start app (after running other apps), you have satellites, but (since you are probably indoors) without the network you may lose satellites little by little, decreasing accuracy.

moral of the story: Use the network provider as well, or make sure you have clear view of the sky to test gps.

Comment: not. As I said: "other apps are able to get fix". when I switched back to my app just after that onLocationChanged is getting called only accuracy is degrading. And fix eventually is lost

Comment: so when you debug this app, you are outside in clear view of the sky?

Comment: yes. 1) I start my app. 2) Wait ~ 10 min - no fix.3) Start GPS Status. get a fix in a couple of minutes 4) Run my app again. 5) See how it reports location with degrading  accuracy. 6) after a while fix is lost